# A continuous complex function that is holomorphic on a dense open subset is holomorphic everywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is as follows:

> Suppose $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is continuous everywhere, and holomorphic on a dense open subset $\Omega  \subset \mathbb C$. Can we deduce that $f$ is in fact holomorphic on the whole of $\mathbb C$?

**Context**

Having not done any math for a long time, I'm reviewing complex analysis by working through Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*. This question came to mind when thinking about a couple of exercises in the book.

- Exercise 11.11. Here, we are asked to prove my claim in the special case where $\partial \Omega$ is a straight line segment. I proved this using Morera's theorem (though this probably wasn't the way the book wanted me to prove it). The exercise then asks the reader to propose other open subsets $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ for which the claim is true, and a natural hypothesis is that this claim is true for all dense $\Omega$. It's difficult to see how to use Morera's theorem to tackle the case of a general open dense $\Omega$, since the geometry of the boundary of $\Omega$ can be very complicated.
- Exercise 12.11 asks the reader to show that if $\Omega$ is an unbounded connected open subset of $\mathbb C$ (not necessarily dense) and if $f: \bar \Omega \to \mathbb C$ is continuous and bounded on $\bar \Omega$ and holomorphic on $\Omega$ with $|f| \leq M$ on $\partial \Omega$, then $|f| \leq M$ on $\Omega$ too. The book provides a lovely hint that solves this problem, but only in the case where $\bar \Omega$ is *not* dense in $\mathbb C$. This makes me suspect that the solution for the case where $\bar \Omega$ is dense in $\mathbb C$ ought to be trivial. If the hypotheses imply that $f$ is holomorphic on the whole of $\mathbb C$ if $\bar \Omega$ is dense in $\mathbb C$, then the solution will indeed be trivial, since we can apply Liouville's theorem to show that $f$ is constant.
- I'd also note that if every point in $\partial \Omega$ is isolated, then the answer to my question will obviously be "yes", since each point in $\partial \Omega$ will be a removable singularity. But in general, $\partial \Omega$ can have limit points, so this line of thought breaks down.

Comment: Look for the concept of analytic capacity as generally a (closed) set is removable as a singular set for a bounded analytic function iff it has analytic capacity zero; there are nowhere dense sets of non zero analytic capacity so the result you ask about is not true in general

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard of the concept of analytic capacity. That's very useful.

Comment: @Conrad The function is assumed to be continuous

Comment: @reuns - yes, so the relevant notion is continuous analytic capacity, which is studied within the context of analytic capacity; for purely unrectifiable curves the notions are similar (in the sense that both the analytic capacity and the continuous analytic capacity are positive - of course for rectifiable curves the continuous analytic capacity is zero); see for example this recent paper by Younsi https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.05198?context=math  something like a piece of the Osgood curve should be purely unrectifiable so give such an example

Comment: Actually, every nowhere dense closed subset of positive measure serves as a counter example.

Comment: Looks complicated. Any easy example of such a continuous non-analytic function? Still trying to figure what kind of sets let us prove Morera's theorem  by deforming curves.